# UIButton doesn't want to keep in Selected State when clicking on the button

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am trying to figure out what's wrong here, because as you can in the screenshots a different image is given for both, selected and default state.

## The problem :

when I run on simulator, I click on the button, it shows the image of highlited state, and then back to the normal state without keeping changed at the selected state ! any hints or ideas about this particular issue ?

[image: Normal State]

[image: Selected State]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should manually set selected state to YES in code when the button is pressed

```
- (IBAction)btnTapped:(UIButton*)button {
    button.selected = !button.selected; // to switch from selected to unselected and vice versa
}
```

Comment: By the way I have 3 buttons on the same page, I want that when I select one of them, the other one get unselected.

Comment: @Al_fareS I think you should create an array of 3 buttons, onTap event set selected to NO for each button from the array and then set selected to yes for current button.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a target to this button and in that method, you should write

```
button.selected=YES;  //then only the image will change.
```

Comment: Can you please more specific ? I am using storyboard, until now nothing related to the button is written.